# Selecting one row per group

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I select one adres per customer with smallest id?

```
ID          ADRESID     CUSTOMERID
132677      1           1
407723      276171      1
132678      22871       1
458243      289         21
458244      276246      21
458242      5           21
26          21          22
25          16          22
407761      276209      22
151356      8227        23
407762      276210      23
```

@edit

Results that i expect:

```
ID          ADRESID     CUSTOMERID
132677      1           1
458242      5           21
25          16          22
151356      8227        23
```

Comment: Sample table data is great, but you'll need to specify the expected result as well!

Comment: show what have you tried and expected output..also your description is not correct

Comment: Try `group by and MIN` function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a window function for the same-

```
SELECT ID, ADRESID, CUSTOMERID
FROM (SELECT ID
            ,ADRESID
            ,CUSTOMERID
            ,RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY CUSTOMERID ORDER BY ID) RN
      FROM YOUR_TAB)
WHERE RN = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use exits clause as well:

```sql
-- Sample data:
WITH your_tab(ID,ADRESID,CUSTOMERID) as (
select 132677,      1     ,      1  from dual union all
select 407723,      276171,      1  from dual union all
select 132678,      22871 ,      1  from dual union all
select 458243,      289   ,      21 from dual union all
select 458244,      276246,      21 from dual union all
select 458242,      5     ,      21 from dual union all
select 26    ,      21    ,      22 from dual union all
select 25    ,      16    ,      22 from dual union all
select 407761,      276209,      22 from dual union all
select 151356,      8227  ,      23 from dual union all
select 407762,      276210,      23 from dual)
-- Query:
SELECT id
     , ADRESID
     , customerid
  FROM your_tab a 
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM your_tab
                    WHERE customerid = a.customerid
                      AND id         < a.id)
```